# TeamCity seems to ignore exit code from NUnit

Tags: nunit, teamcity

I've got a build that completed successfully, but the number of completed tests is about 50% lower than I was expecting. On closer inspection, it seems that the Mono instance running NUnit died with SIGABRT. (!!) Yet TeamCity still considers this a *successful* test run, since none of the *tests* returned a failure condition.

How do I force TeamCity to consider this a failed build? (TeamCity 8.x)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same problem occurs with TeamCity 9 if an NUnit [OneTimeSetUp] function fails. No tests run, NUnit returns with exit code 1, but TeamCity considers it a success.

If there's anything in the build log relating to your SIGABRT, you can add a Failure Condition, e.g.:

- Fail build if its build log ...
- contains text matching regexp ...
- "SIGABRT" or in my case "Process exited with code [^0]"